# Find Outlook AppointmentItem for ContactItem

Tags: c#, outlook, office-interop, outlook-2010

I am creating `ContactItem` from code using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook`. This works absolutely fine. If I assign a the property `Birthday`, an corresponding `AppointmentItem` is created automatically. This is also fine.

But now when I delete the `ContactItem`, the `AppointmentItem` stays. This is obviously not what I was going for.

```
localContactToDelete.Delete();
```

Is there a way to retrieve the associated `AppointmentItem` in order to delete it manually?

I read that it should be possible (see below), however I do not find the propoerties or whatever.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/6b481f74-8422-46d4-90a9-a5860dcb98b5/to-avoid-automatic-birthday-calendar-event-creation-when-creating-contact?forum=outlookdev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Dmitry's tip for using OutlookSpy to identify the NameSchema of the needed property I came up with the following code. It's definitely not ready, but at least works for the moment. Any suggestions welcome.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application outlookObject = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();

MAPIFolder contactFolder = outlookObject.Session.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderContacts);
Items contacts = contactFolder.Items;
```

Then comes the stuff selecting the contact, e.g. a foreach.

```
ContactItem contact;

PropertyAccessor pa = contact.PropertyAccessor;
Byte[] ba = pa.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/id/{00062004-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/804D0102");
string birthdayAppointmentItemID = BitConverter.ToString(ba).Replace("-", string.Empty);

NameSpace ns = outlookObject.GetNamespace("MAPI");
AppointmentItem birthdayAppointmentItem = ns.GetItemFromID(birthdayAppointmentItemID);
```

Comment: Don't loop through all appointments - if you know the entry id, just call Namespace.GetItemFromId.

Comment: Good point, thanks for the comment. I updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at a contact with the birthday/anniversary properties set using [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy) (I am its author - click IMessage) - the entry id of the birthday appointment is stored in a named property with the DASL name of `http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/id/{00062004-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/804D0102`. For the anniversary, use `http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/id/{00062004-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/804E0102`.